# Organizing array of objects by name/quantity

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

The objective is to go through the array of objects and figure out which `itemName` was ordered the most (`quantity`).

From here, the `itemName` that was ordered the most we want to put on `shelfName 1`.

2nd most ordered `itemName` would go on `shelfName 2` and so on.

### Input

The order repository contains information about yesterdays orders.

```
 function main() {

  var orderRepo = new OrderRepository();

  // CODE HERE

 }
```

### Output

Display the shelf and item pairings by calling the following function:

`displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName);`

Execute your program my opening main.html in your web browser to see the results.

```js
    let yesterdaysOrders = [

    {
        id: 1,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 01", quantity: 1 },
            { itemName: "Item 02", quantity: 3 },
            { itemName: "Item 03", quantity: 25 },
            { itemName: "Item 04", quantity: 12 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 01", quantity: 1 },
            { itemName: "Item 08", quantity: 42 },
            { itemName: "Item 09", quantity: 13 },
            { itemName: "Item 12", quantity: 37 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 12", quantity: 16 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 10", quantity: 11 },
            { itemName: "Item 11", quantity: 10 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 06", quantity: 7 },
            { itemName: "Item 07", quantity: 2 },
            { itemName: "Item 12", quantity: 14 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 05", quantity: 17 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 03", quantity: 5 },
            { itemName: "Item 07", quantity: 2 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 02", quantity: 13 },
            { itemName: "Item 07", quantity: 7 },
            { itemName: "Item 09", quantity: 2 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 01", quantity: 4 },
            { itemName: "Item 06", quantity: 17 },
            { itemName: "Item 07", quantity: 3 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 11", quantity: 12 },
            { itemName: "Item 12", quantity: 1 },
        ],
    }
    ],
    result = Array.from(
      yesterdaysOrders.reduce((m, { orderLines }) => {
         orderLines.forEach(({ itemName, quantity }) => m.set(itemName, (m.get(itemName) || 0) + quantity));
        return m;
    }, new Map),
      ([itemName, quantity]) => ({ itemName, quantity })
    );
 
    console.log(result);
```

Right now, it's listing the totals of each `itemName`, but the items are not on the right shelf.

Now I need to add the proper `itemName` with the most `quantity` to the right shelves.

How could I go about combining the right `shelfName` to the right `itemName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the array on quantity in descending order.

```
// Sorting on quantity in descending order.
result.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.quantity > b.quantity) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.quantity < b.quantity) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

And then put each item in shelf by iterating over the array.

```
var shelfs = {};

for (var i in result) {
  shelfs["Shelf " + (Number(i) + 1)] = result[i].itemName;
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
let yesterdaysOrders = [

    {
        id: 1,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 01", quantity: 1 },
            { itemName: "Item 02", quantity: 3 },
            { itemName: "Item 03", quantity: 25 },
            { itemName: "Item 04", quantity: 12 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 01", quantity: 1 },
            { itemName: "Item 08", quantity: 42 },
            { itemName: "Item 09", quantity: 13 },
            { itemName: "Item 12", quantity: 37 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 12", quantity: 16 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 10", quantity: 11 },
            { itemName: "Item 11", quantity: 10 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 06", quantity: 7 },
            { itemName: "Item 07", quantity: 2 },
            { itemName: "Item 12", quantity: 14 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 05", quantity: 17 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 03", quantity: 5 },
            { itemName: "Item 07", quantity: 2 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 02", quantity: 13 },
            { itemName: "Item 07", quantity: 7 },
            { itemName: "Item 09", quantity: 2 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 01", quantity: 4 },
            { itemName: "Item 06", quantity: 17 },
            { itemName: "Item 07", quantity: 3 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        orderLines: [
            { itemName: "Item 11", quantity: 12 },
            { itemName: "Item 12", quantity: 1 },
        ],
    }
    ],
    result = Array.from(
      yesterdaysOrders.reduce((m, { orderLines }) => {
         orderLines.forEach(({ itemName, quantity }) => m.set(itemName, (m.get(itemName) || 0) + quantity));
        return m;
    }, new Map),
      ([itemName, quantity]) => ({ itemName, quantity })
    );

 // Sorting on quantity.
result.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.quantity > b.quantity) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.quantity < b.quantity) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
 
var shelfs = {};

for (var i in result) {
  shelfs["Shelf " + (Number(i) + 1)] = result[i].itemName;
}

function displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName) {
  console.log(shelfName + " : " + itemName);
}

for (var i in  shelfs) {
  displayShelfItemPair(i, shelfs[i]);
}
```

Comment: appreciate the response, it's asking me to to use this function `displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName);`

Comment: @mph85 - What should be the expected output of that function? It is taking both `shelfName` and `itemName` so it is not clear what should be displayed.

Comment: *   Shelf 1:      Item 12
*   Shelf 2:      Item 11
*   Shelf 3:      Item 10
*   Shelf 4:      Item 09
*   Shelf 5:      Item 08
*   Shelf 6:      Item 07
*   Shelf 7:      Item 06
*   Shelf 8:      Item 05
*   Shelf 9:      Item 04
*   Shelf 10:     Item 03
*   Shelf 11:     Item 02
*   Shelf 12:     Item 01
*
* Display the shelf and item pairings by calling the following function:
*   displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName);

Comment: @mph85 - I wrapped the code in `displayShelfItemPair()` function. Check out my edited answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: appreciate it, but the instructions are kinda strict, I nee d to use that function and the parameters with it

Comment: @mph85 - What should be passed as arguments `shelfName` and `itemName` ? What is the use of them when we are displaying the whole shelf items.

Comment: that's what im trying to figure out, lemme see if there's any other instructions

Comment: @mph85 - I modified the function to use those arguments. Perhaps this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it in a few passes will be less efficient, but easier to follow.
Something like this:

```
// add to shelf
let r = yesterdaysOrders.reduce((shelves, order) => {
  order.orderLines.forEach(item => {
    shelves[item.itemName] = (shelves[item.itemName] || 0) + item.quantity;
  });
  return shelves;
}, {});

// sort by most orders
let sorted = Object.entries(r).sort((left, right) => right[1] - left[1])
let sortedShelves = Object.fromEntries(sorted)
```

```
output:
:!node test.js
{
  'Item 12': 68,
  'Item 08': 42,
  'Item 03': 30,
  'Item 06': 24,
  'Item 11': 22,
  'Item 05': 17,
  'Item 02': 16,
  'Item 09': 15,
  'Item 07': 14,
  'Item 04': 12,
  'Item 10': 11,
  'Item 01': 6
}
```

Comment: appreciate the response, it's asking me to to use this function `displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName);`